# jQuery function doesn't work in a JavaScript for-loop. Please Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, function, for-loop

I've posted variations of this question before and just as I think I've got it, it doesn't work again.

I figured out the problem though, but have no answer. When I execute this code it works just fine:

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1">';
    for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) { 
            var $eqn = "ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+") .article-title a span";  
        }
        $($eqn).replaceWith($titleMarquee+$(this).text()+"</marquee>");
    }
```

But as soon as I put in an event like .mouseenter it screws up and stops working:

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1">';
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<3;j++) { 
        var $eqn = "ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+") .article-title a span";  
    }
    $($eqn).mouseenter(function(){
        $($eqn).replaceWith($titleMarquee+$(this).text()+"</marquee>");
    }); 
}
```

What else is strange that I've figured out is part of the problem is when both the .event and .replaceWith have a variable. If I just assign a variable to the .mouseenter and use $(this) for .replaceWith it works fine but restricts me from what I want to do. I can't even use ("+i+").

This is what I want to achieve with the script and it doesn't work this way. Please help.

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1">';
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<3;j++) { 
        $("ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+")").mouseenter(function(){
            $("ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+") .article-title a span").replaceWith($titleMarquee+$(this).text()+"</marquee>");
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start with removing the inner loop and thinking of assigning that mouseenver event with a single selection of all 3 elements.  That's if I understand correctly...

Comment: Is that a `marquee`? o_O

Comment: Watch out where you are declaring and using variables. In the third block you are using `i` in event handler, but it changes to 6, because it is from outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this instead:

```
$("ul.side-block-content li").mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $titleMarquee =
        $('<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1"></marquee>');

    $(".article-title a span", $this)
        .replaceWith($titleMarquee.text($this.text()));
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mXtmB/

If you want to limit the `li` elements so that the event is applied to to the first 6:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $("ul.side-block-content li:eq(" + i + ")").mouseenter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $titleMarquee =
        $('<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1"></marquee>');

        $(".article-title a span", $this)
            .replaceWith($titleMarquee.text($this.text()));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to test it right now, check if this is working.

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1">';
var i, j; // important
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $("ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+")").mouseenter(function(){
            $("ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+") .article-title a span").replaceWith($titleMarquee+$(this).text()+"</marquee>");
        });   
    }(i));
}
```

I also deleted that pointless loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `$eqn` variable to access the element, you will be accessing the last element, as the value of the variable has changed since you hooked up the event. Use the `this` keyword to access the element that the event is hooked up to:

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1">';
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
  $("ul.side-block-content li:eq("+i+") .article-title a span").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($titleMarquee+$(this).text()+"</marquee>");
  });
}
```